# Can an isotopy between diffeomorphisms be through diffeomorphisms?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (without boundary). Suppose $F:M \times I \rightarrow M$ is a smooth (say $C^{\infty}$) isotopy between two diffeomorphisms $f_0$ and $f_1$ of M in the sense that  $\forall t \in I ,F(\cdot,t):M\rightarrow M $ is an embedding and that $F(\cdot,0)=f_0,F(\cdot,1)=f_1$. My question is can we find a new isotopy $\tilde{F}$ between $f_0$ and $f_1$ such that $\forall t \in I,\tilde{F}(\cdot,t) $ is a diffeomorphism?

For exmaple if M is a compact manifold. By the isotopy extension theorem, there is an ambient isotopy $\Phi:M\times I \rightarrow M$ such that $\Phi(\cdot,0)=id_M,\Phi(1,f_0(\cdot))=f_1(\cdot)$. Then $\Phi(\cdot,f_0(\cdot))$ is an isotopy between $f_0$ and $f_1$ through diffeomorphism. I wonder if this is true in general. Thank you!

Comment: The target spaces will vary so it seems impossible in a general case

Comment: You should clarify your definition of a smooth isotopy: The usual reading is that it is an isotopy through diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Yes, it seems. But I wonder if there is a counterexample.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for your reminding. I have edited the question. I use the definition from Chapter 8 of Hirsch's book "Differential Topology", where isotopies are through embeddings and ambient isotopies are through diffeomorphisms.

Comment: For a compact manifold $M$ every embedding $M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism. As for your question, it looks hard and is probably false. Why do you need it?